# JAX-RS 2.0 service in WAS Liberty: Getting CWWKS1100A even though REST Filter is authenticating correctly

Tags: rest, jax-rs, websphere-liberty

I am using a REST Auth filter:

```
@Provider
 @PreMatching
 @Stateless
 public class ContainerRequestAuthFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
 ...
 }
```

The service works OK and authenticates correctly my REST requests but before the method filter() is executed I always get multiple annoying CWWKS1100A errors. After that I get the confirmation (logged in the INFO line shown above by my filter showing that the request is granted access to the service).

```
 [AUDIT   ] CWWKS1100A: Authentication did not succeed for user ID XXXX. An invalid user ID or password was specified.
 [INFO    ] Authorized access to v0.1/token to user XXXX OK.
```

Everything is working but I want to get rid of those error messages. How can I solve this? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you know these messages are harmless, add `<logging hideMessage ="CWWKS1100A"/>` to your server.xml file, which should suppress that message.

Logging options are documented here: 
http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSD28V_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.core.doc/ae/rwlp_config_logging.html

For general information about logging & trace in Liberty: 
http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSD28V_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.core.doc/ae/rwlp_logging.html

Comment: Thanks but I then would be missing a real authentication problem for a user so I am not sure I want to implement this (good do know the logging option hideMessage. Thanks)